# Why I am getting wrong output for source string when I am implementing strcat()?

Tags: arrays, c, string, strcat

Here I tried implementing `strcat` function in C. Problem is that when I am printing the source string it is showing me `"hyam"`  not `"shyam"`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *fun(char *target, const char *source) {
    printf("%s\n", source);
    int x = strlen(target);
    while (*source != '\0') {
        *(target + x++) = *source++;
    }
    *(target + x) = '\0';
    return target;
}

int main() {
    char target[] = "ram";
    char source[] = "shyam";
    fun(target, source);
    printf("%s\n", target);
    printf("%s", source);
    return 0;
}
```

Here in last line of output `hyam` is shown but it should be `shyam`.

```
shyam
ramshyam
hyam
```

Comment: Because you can't push into the array more than it's size.

Comment: in c++ you should use `std::string`

Comment: `target` is an array with four elements, and it needs at least nine. Reading or writing outside an array has undefined behaviour.

Comment: It's not necessarily the problem but `int x=strlen(target)` should be `size_t x`.

Comment: If question does not address C++ explicitly please don't add that tag! This looks like a pure C question. However, in C `main` should be declared as `int main(void)`, if you don't need command line arguments.

Comment: Side note: There's syntactic sugar for `*(array + index)`: `array[index]`...

Comment: You don't need that offset at all if you simply do: `target += strlen(target);` – then you can have `*target++ = *source++` inside the loop.

Comment: `char target[]="ram"` is equivalent to `char target[4]="ram"`. There is only space for 3 characters (+ the terminating null). You want e.g. `char target[100]="ram";`, then there will be space for 99 characters.

Comment: C or C++ tag please pick one!

Comment: You should do

`do { *target++ = *source++; } while(*source);`

In this way, testing for NUL character at the end, you also copy the final NUL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `target` array is too small - it needs at least nine elements (the length of both strings plus a terminating zero).

Writing outside `target` has undefined behaviour, but in practice, it looks like your arrays happen to be laid out end to end, like this:

```
 |r|a|m|\0|s|h|y|a|m|\0|
 ^        ^
 |        | 
target   source
```

and then you concatenate, going past the end of `target` into `source`:

```
 |r|a|m|s|h|y|a|m|\0|\0|
 ^       ^
 |       | 
target  source
```

which makes it look like an `'s'` has disappeared.

(Note that this is *undefined*, so anything can happen. You can't rely on this behaviour, unless the documentation for your compiler says that it's fine and should do this. Which it most likely won't.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the array `target` defined with `char target[] = "ram";` is too short to accommodate appending the contents of the `source` string.  You must make `target` larger, at least 9 bytes, 8 for the characters and one more for the null terminator:

```
char target[9] = "ram";
```

Comment: You are correct. I shall amend the answer promptly